# Bourne shell script, finding highest value in column 1 for specific value in column 3

Tags: awk, sh

As the title puts it, i want to find the highest value in column 1 for each specific value in column 3. Then i want to print out column 2 for that line which has the ip-address, and column 3 with the errorcode.

My code:

```
cat $NAME |awk '{print $1, $9}' | sort -k 1 -k 2 | uniq -c | sort -k 3
```

[Part of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLeuc.jpg)

Forgot to mention that we are opening a logfile that we put in the variable 'NAME" and in the logfile there are more than 9 columns. The 9 reffers to the server response code. Here's an example of a line in the logfile:

127.0.0.1 - stefan [01/Apr/2002:12:17:10 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 301 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Konqueror/2.2.2-2; Linux)"

Comment: Where do you get nine (`9`) values (e.g. `$9`) from an *index*, an *IP Address* and the *server response code* if your field delimiter is the default? (that would provide a max of `3` if your output reflects your input)

Comment: Forgot to mention that we are opening a logfile that we put in the variable 'NAME" and in the logfile there are more than 9 columns. The 9 reffers to the server response code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring your code snippet, which seems totally unrelated to your description of the problem (I do not understand the presence of `$9`), I think you want:

```
sort -s -k3,3 -k1,1r $NAME | awk '$3 != l{print $2, $3; l=$3}'
```

All of the specific values in column 3 appear in continguous groups.   The secondary key (`-k1,1r`) then sorts each group with the highest value in column 1 appearing first.  The awk then prints just the first line of each group by printing the 2nd and 3rd columns each time a new value appears in the 3rd column.

Comment: The code i put is what gets the output on the picture, i forgot to mention i had a logfile which we open first. The $9 is reffering to the server response code in the logfile.

Comment: Your pre-processing makes no sense, as it only generates 2 columns.  So how can you have questions about column 3?

Comment: I added your code to mine and it works fine, the only thing i changed was from sort -s to sort -g. Thanks for the help!